# Как обрабатывать нажатия на кнопки Telegram Bot - Golang

Tags: telegram-bot, golang

пишу тедеграм бота на golang с использованием библиотеки *github.com/Syfaro/telegram-bot-api*. Застрял на моменте когда мне нужно обработать нажатие пользователем на кнопку в сообщении.

Вот пример кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я получаю канал с обновлениями и читаю из него сообщения которые пользователь отправил боту

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку в сообщении, то это событие не попадает в канал *Updates* и я не понимаю каким образом мне обработать нажатие на эту кнопку. Я использую *InlineKeyboardButtonData* и мне так же нужно получить данные которые содержатся в этой кнопке

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, надо было проверку на сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написать ниже чем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не используйте в вопросах и в ответах скриншоты, замените на код